# Google Analytics 400 Error - Restricted dimension(s): ga:adsense metrics can only be queried under certain conditions

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I'm using Google Analytics Core Reporting API v3 and I get this error message:

> An error has occured
> Error code: 400
>
> Error message: Restricted dimension(s): ga:adsensePageImpressions, metric(s): ga:adsensePageImpressions, ga:adsenseCTR, ga:adsenseAdsClicks, ga:adsenseRevenue can only be queried under certain conditions. For details see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets.

**My dimensions:** ga:campaign, ga:hour
**My metrics:** ga:sessions, ga:adsenseRevenue, ga:adsenseCTR, ga:adsenseAdsClicks, ga:adsensePageImpressions, ga:pageviewsPerSession

According to the given url (than redirects me to https://ga-dev-tools.google/dimensions-metrics-explorer/) this combination of dimensions is valid.

Has anyone encountered this error?